Updating status of CPA
I am looking for a way to update the status of CPA via APS API (i.e. change the status from Approved to Paid, when linked purchase order in our ERP gets processed).
Can someone point me where I can find the proper procedure please?

Is this PATCH Expense API something you are looking for? You can update the status of the expense when it's changed in your ERP system.
